# dot hover area offset in gRaphael line chart

Tags: hover, charts, raphael, offset, graphael

I'm trying to get a hover effect for displaying information against points on a line chart using gRaphael.  I've got a basic version working here http://www.matthewhollings.co.uk/svg/raphael-line-test.html but there seems to be an offset against the point that the hover responds to when two lines are close together.  Does anyone know how I can fix this so that each point responds when the mouse pointer is closest?

Also, I'm trying to make the line chart look more like the one on the raphael website, where the hover flag contains both the x and y value of the point and is animated along the path.  Any help with that would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks in advance,
Matt

Comment: link is broken, please point to a working demo, thanks.